# AngularJS - need access in index.html page to data from a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I need to place code on every page of my app in index.html (Google Analytics tracking code). The issue is that some of the code needs to pull values from an Angular service. I'm wondering what the best practice is for doing this?

I was thinking to have run block that uses an injected service to get the value. I could then set a constant that I would have access to in index.html. I'm not sure if that's possible or not.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a good way to do it. I also use `ga( "send", "pageview", $location.path() );` on the `$routeChangeSuccess` event in the `.run` block.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how to get index.html access to the constants. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Try using resolve in your routes and then the data can be passed into each controller

Comment: Constants are only available to Angular objects. Index.html isn't an Angular object, so I'm not sure how to just get the value of the constant there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do, but it sounds like its as simple as retrieving a value from a service and binding it to a tag on your page.

In your controller:

```
$scope.yourConstant = yourInjectedService.getValue();
```

Then in your index.html:

```
<span>{{ yourConstant }}</span>
```

or:

```
<span ng-bind='yourConstant'></span>
```

IF I've misunderstood please try to clarify your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue is that I need to place code on the index.html page and I'm setting the constant in a run block. There's no controller or scope that I'm using at this point, so I don't know how to actually get access to the constant on the index.html page.

Comment: so there's no controller scope for your index page?  So you need to get it from a controller and put it on the index page outside of the scope of that controller?

Comment: That's the thing. I'm not sure how to get the index.html page to have access to it (I'm new to AngularJS). It seems like I need to set it in some Angular object or global scope?

Comment: there is $rootScope that is the topmost scope in the angular app that you can access between other scopes, but now that I've looked around a little (i'm new to google analytics) I suspect that what you are going for is to track route changes and such so google doesn't just see the index.html page.